# Can I disable the "release to select" of my context menus in favor of "click to select"?

Tags: gui, context-menu

In every program I've tested this in (VSCode, Firefox, Thunderbird, and Nemo) on Ubuntu 22.04, if you right-click to bring up the context menu *and continue holding the right-click*, then move the cursor over an option from the context menu and release, that option will be selected ("clicked on"). I would like to change this behavior so that when I bring up the context menu, I have to release right-click again and then both click down *and* release the click on an option to select it.

I'm not even sure which piece of software on my machine is responsible for the behavior of context menus. GNOME? X11? Is there a way to make this work differently? If not, is there some component of my machine that I could look into replacing or even compiling a custom version of that would change this across all (or at least most) programs? I realize programs are free to implement their own context menus any way they want, but somebody on my machine must be providing some kind of default implementation.